# Is there any solution for keyboard changing when secureTextEntry prop of TextInput changes on react native?

Tags: react-native, keyboard, textinput, react-native-textinput

I'm working with a login screen, and I have that eye icon so I can hide or reveal the password content. But when I update the state of the icon, the keyboard of the mobile phone changes.
Is there any way to keep the keyboard in the same way in both cases?

I tried to change the prop keyboardType, but it still changes.

**That's with the secureTextInput unabled**
[image: That's with the secureTextInput unabled]

**That's with the secureTextInput abled**
[image: That's with the secureTextInput abled]

***As you can see, the number keyboard appears and disappears, so the full app interface translates.***

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you have implemented the code so far , But try like this ,

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, Text } from 'react-native';

const LoginScreen = () => {
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [isPasswordVisible, setPasswordVisible] = useState(false);

  const togglePasswordVisibility = () => {
    setPasswordVisible(!isPasswordVisible);
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <TextInput
        secureTextEntry={!isPasswordVisible}
        value={password}
        onChangeText={setPassword}
        placeholder="Password"
      />
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={togglePasswordVisibility}>
         <Image
              source={isPasswordVisible  ? images.eyeOpen : images.eyeClose}
              style={styles.icon}
            />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};

export default LoginScreen;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  icon: {
    width: 20,
    height: 20,
  },
  });
```

You have to change styles to make a perfect textInput with eyeIcon to the right .